# wrapper printf function that filters according to user preferences

Tags: c, filter, printf, wrapper

My program writes to a log and to stdout. Every message, however, has a certain priority and the user specifies in Preferences which priorities go to which stream (log or stdout).

```
unsigned short PRIO_HIGH = 0x0001;
unsigned short PRIO_NORMAL = 0x0002;
unsigned short PRIO_LOW = 0x0004;
```

The preferences is handled by some flags:

```
unsigned short PRIO_LOG = (PRIO_HIGH | PRIO_NORMAL);
unsigned short PRIO_STD = (PRIO_HIGH);
```

The `write_log` function should work with the same parameters as the printf function, with the added parameter of `unsigned short priority`.

```
write_log((PRIO_NORMAL|PRIO_LOW), "HELLO %s, take %d", "World", 1);
```

(Even if `PRIO_NORMAL|PRIO_LOW` makes little sense...)

Checking the flags is easy: `if(priority & PRIO_LOG)` (Returns >1 if any flag is set in both arguments)

I cannot however find out how I would go about passing the string literal *and* the format arguments to the printf function. Can anyone help or give me a pointer (possible to an alternative method that achieves the same effect)? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You want to call vprintf() instead of printf() using the variable arguments "[varargs](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_28.html)" capabilities of C.

```
#include <stdarg.h>

int write_log(int priority, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    if(priority & PRIO_LOG)
            vprintf(format, args);

    va_end(args);
}
```

For more information, see something along the lines of [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vprintf/).

Comment: In Visual C++ you can use _____VA_ARGS_____ instead. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 11):

I think Jeff's idea is the way to go, but you can also accomplish this with a macro without using vprintf.  This might require gcc:

```
#define write_log(priority,format,args...)        \
                  if (priority & PRIO_LOG) {      \ 
                      printf(format, ## args);    \
                  }
```

Check [here](http://docs.freebsd.org/info/gcc/gcc.info.Macro_Varargs.html) for info about how this works.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the PRIO_* definitions to be used as bit (using | and &), you must give each one of them its own bit:

```
unsigned short PRIO_HIGH = 0x0001;
unsigned short PRIO_NORMAL = 0x0002;
unsigned short PRIO_LOW = 0x0004;
```

The macro can be improved by using the do { } while (0) notation. It makes the calls to write_log act more like a statement.

```
#define write_log(priority,format,args...) do { \
    if (priority & PRIO_LOG) { \
        printf(format, ## args); \
    } while(0)
```

Comment: Sorry, Type. I did it like that in my source of course. thanks for the pointing out! +1 for a keen eye.