# How would I use the `...` C operator to get a function to print out all it's args?

Tags: c, function, printf, arguments

Here's what I tried... but failed:

```
void testfunc(...){
    printf(...);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing variable arguments to another function that accepts a variable argument list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530771/passing-variable-arguments-to-another-function-that-accepts-a-variable-argument-l)

Comment: I'm not sure if the suggested duplicate really is an exact duplicate (it isn't really that clear what you want to achieve here), however in any case it is very similar and should help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [`va_start()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_start/), [`va_end()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_end/), [`va_arg()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_arg/) and (not always) [`va_list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_list/) and you must have at least one constant defined argument! For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void PrintFloats ( int amount, ...)
{
  int i;
  double val;
  printf ("Floats passed: ");
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl,amount);
  for (i=0;i<amount;i++)
  {
    val=va_arg(vl,double);
    printf ("\t%.2f",val);
  }
  va_end(vl);
  printf ("\n");
}

int main ()
{
  PrintFloats (3,3.14159,2.71828,1.41421);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will create a function that is equivalent to `printf`.  Note that you cannot blindly print out arguments, since you somehow need to know what type each argument is in advance.  The `format` argument to printf informs it what arguments to expect and what types they will be.

```
#include <stdargs.h>

void testfunc(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);

    vprintf(format, ap);

    va_end(ap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `va_start()` and `va_end()` macros, but you'll have to have at least one argument:

```
void testfunc(int n, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, n); // initialize the va_list
    // something useful
    va_end(vl); // deinitializes vl
}
```

You can sequentially access the arguments with `va_arg(vl, type)` (e.g. `int x = va_arg(vl, int)`). Also, `va_copy` is occasionally useful if you want to copy the current state of the `va_list`