# function with args is calling another function with same args

Tags: c++, c, arguments

I want to develop a c function with random number of arguments:

```
int myfunction(char *fmt,...) {
....
}
```

then in my function I want to call `printf()` with the same input arguments of my function (the `fmt` and the other random arguments):

```
int myfunction(char *fmt,...) {
    ....
    printf(/*What I have to put here?*/)
    ....
}
```

How I can call `printf()` in this case?

Comment: You will probably need to use `vprintf()` in this case, along with `va_start()`, `va_arg()`, etc...

Comment: Not to mention [Passing variable arguments to another function that accepts a variable argument list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530771/passing-variable-arguments-to-another-function-that-accepts-a-variable-argument/3530807#3530807) or [Forward an invocation of a variadic function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c).