# Use ellipsis (...) in recurent function calls

Tags: c, ellipsis

I want to write a function writelog() with ellipsis parameters, which should forward the same ellipsis parameters to another function. How to do it?

My function example:

```
void writetolog(char *format, ...)
{
    FILE *file;
    if ((file = fopen(LOG_FILE, "a")) != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(file, format, ...);
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Function fprintf() should have the same ellipsis parameters from function writetolog().

Comment: Look at `vfprintf`

Comment: man stdarg :: `#include <stdarg.h>

       void va_start(va_list ap, last);`

Comment: (for your searching pleasure, it's known as variable arguments, not ellipsis)

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible, the `...` arguments cannot be passed on directly.

What you generally do is implement the lowest layer using an explicit argument list (`va_list`) argument, and solve it that way.

In your case, if the lowest layer is the standard library's printing, then you need to call [`vfprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/vfprintf) with an explicit `va_list` that holds the arguments to your function:

```
void writetolog(const char *format, ...)
{
    FILE * const file = fopen(LOG_FILE, "a");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        vfprintf(file, format, args);
        va_end(args);
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Note that in a C macro, you can use the special symbol `__VA_ARGS__` to refer to the variable arguments list, but that's not available in functions.

Comment: It is possible, I was doing it once, but I have forgot function name.

Comment: @PeterPolak That sounds a bit like [Fermat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Fermat's_conjecture).

Answer (score 4):

Use the `vfprintf` function:

```
#include <stdarg.h>             // vararg macros

void writetolog(char *format, ...)
{
    FILE *file;
    if ((file = fopen(LOG_FILE, "a")) != NULL)
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start (args, format);

        vfprintf(file, format, args);
        fclose(file);
        va_end(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: @spectras, indeed. "_If va_end is not called before returning from the function, the result is undefined._. Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly; you have to create a function that takes a va_list:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

static void exampleV(int b, va_list args);

void example(int a, int b, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, b);
    exampleV(b, args);
    va_end(args);
}

void exampleB(int b, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, b);
    exampleV(b, args);
    va_end(args);
}

static void exampleV(int b, va_list args)
{
    ...whatever you planned to have exampleB do...
    ...except it calls neither va_start nor va_end...
}
```

Taken from [Passing variable arguments to another function that accepts a variable argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530771/passing-variable-arguments-to-another-function-that-accepts-a-variable-argument/3530807)