# Custom snprintf() function gives wrong output

Tags: arduino, embedded

### Background

I'm trying to write a wrapper function for `snrpintf()` on an embedded platform (Arduino) to have a shorthand for writing into a buffer then printing it over the Serial port.

### Problem

As long as I write out the full code everything works, but this is rather verbose. So, I decided to write a function for it, which, alas, doesn't work.

It looks like the pointer doesn't get set properly, as the output is total rubbish.

### Example

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define AVR_PRINTF_BUFF_SIZE 127

void avrPrintf(const char *fmt, ...) {

    char avr_printf_buffer[AVR_PRINTF_BUFF_SIZE] = {};

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    snprintf(avr_printf_buffer, AVR_PRINTF_BUFF_SIZE, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    Serial.print(avr_printf_buffer);
}


void setup() {

    Serial.begin(19200);
    delay(1000);

    Serial.println("Without a function:");
    char buffer[AVR_PRINTF_BUFF_SIZE] = {};
    snprintf(buffer, AVR_PRINTF_BUFF_SIZE, "%d.%02d.%02d %02d:%02d:%02d Weekday: %02d\r\n\n", 1985, 5, 15, 14, 0, 32, 3);
    Serial.print(buffer);

    Serial.println("From a function:");
    avrPrintf("%d.%02d.%02d %02d:%02d:%02d Weekday: %02d\r\n", 1985, 5, 15, 14, 0, 32, 3);
}


void loop() {
    ;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Without a function:
1985.05.15 14:00:32 Weekday: 03

From a function:
2139.12594.14643 12590:13618:13369 Weekday: 12590
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use [`vsnprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) in your function?

Comment: And if you're really programming in C++ then I suggest you come up with other more type-safe ways than the old `printf` family.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530771/passing-variable-arguments-to-another-function-that-accepts-a-variable-argument

Comment: Holy cow! Yes, this makes all the difference. I can't believe I spent 3 hours trying to figure out why this wasn't working. I thought `vsnprintf()` was for printing into stdout, but that's `vfprintf()`. Oh, my. Thank's for your help!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Do you have any pointers I could look into re: more type-safe ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
snprintf(avr_printf_buffer, AVR_PRINTF_BUFF_SIZE, fmt, args);
```

`args` becomes an argument to `snprintf` just like an `int` or a `float`. This causes undefined behavior since the object type expected by the format specifier is not found there. You'll need to use `vsnprintf` instead.

```
vsnprintf(avr_printf_buffer, AVR_PRINTF_BUFF_SIZE, fmt, args);
```