# Separate different types of arguments from va_list

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am trying to write a macro which gets the information and sends that information to another function by splitting the orginal va_list into string and another va_list spawned from the original one.

Below is my code.

**Call to macro**

```
/* Usage */
PRINT_LOG("Format log = %d, %f, %s", 1, 2.7, "Test");
```

**My code below**

```
/* my includes here */
#include <stdarg.h>

void printInfo(int level, const char *debugInfo, ...); /* defined in 3rd party API */

void formatLogs(int level, ...);

#define PRINT_LOG(...) formatLogs(0, __VA_ARGS__)

void formatLogs(int level, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, level);

  /* get the first argument from va_list */
  const char *debugString = va_arg(args, const char*);

  /* here I want to get the rest of the variable args received from PRINT_LOG*/
  va_list restOfArgs = ???????; /* restOfArgs should be 1, 2.7, "Test" */

  /* Below I want to send the rest of the arguments */
  printInfo(level, debugString, args);
  va_end(args);
}
```

Is it possible to send some part of va_list as va_list to another function?? If so, how can i do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can pass a `va_list` to another function (see `vfprintf()` etc.) but I don't know if it's okay to do so after using `va_arg()` on it. There's also `va_copy()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variable arguments to another function that accepts a variable argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530771/passing-variable-arguments-to-another-function-that-accepts-a-variable-argument)

Comment: @P.W, I am trying to pass ONLY a part of va_list as va_list to another function. NOT the whole va_list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do, based on the code in your question, is to redefine the macro like so:

```
#define PRINT_LOG(s, ...) printInfo(0, s, __VA_ARGS__)
```

and just skip the intermediate function altogether. Because what you're trying to do can't be done like that.

The `, ...)` variable argument ellipsis is *not* a `va_list`. The variable arguments passed to a function aren't realized as a `va_list` until `va_start` is invoked. To pass a `va_list` as a function argument, the function has to have a `va_list` in its signature, like this:

```
int vprintf(const char *format, va_list argList);
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much. For passing a part of the va_list, I can use va_copy.