# Printf wrapper in C++

Tags: c++, printf, wrapper

Im trying to build a sick function, it's basically a wrapper around printf.

I need to build a char* buffer with vsnprintf. This is the signature of the function that does that:
`char* make_buffer_fmt(char foo, const char* fmt, ...)`

Now, there is, of course, another function wrapping around this function:
`int write_fmt(int fd, char foo, const char* fmt, ...)`

And another one wrapping around `write_fmt`:
`int log(const char* fmt, ...)`

How do pass on the parameter pack from `log` to `make_buffer_fmt`?
I don't want grab the va_list 'manually' everytime. (I fear there is no other way?)

You're probably gonna tell me parameter pack and va_list don't mix well but I'm kinda new to C++ and I'm honestly already glad when it compiles sometimes. The way I have it now, I get the va_list where I need it, in `make_buffer_fmt` but, of course it just reads some random memory because the va_list is not passed on.

I like the three dots, because it copies the printf behaviour, which is ultimately the goal. When I change the `...` to va_list args, it doesn't want my char* anymore :(.

Edit 2: I think my question wasn't that clear so here is some code:

```
int log_info(const char *fmt, ...) { // Is this how I have to do it? 
    va_list va;                      // Problem I have with this, it that write_fmt doesn't have the '...'
    va_start(va, fmt);               // Instead, I have to pass the va_list to write_fmt, which is not what I want. 
    return write_fmt(LOG_FILENO, LOG_INFO, fmt, va); // Because I want to be able to call write_fmt like this: write_fmt(LOG_FILENO, LOG_INFO, "Hello %s", "World");
    va_end(va);
}
```

Edit: Here is the solution but it's ugly and impractical and a lot of boilerplate code: [Passing variable arguments to another function that accepts a variable argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530771/passing-variable-arguments-to-another-function-that-accepts-a-variable-argument)

Comment: Is there no `make_buffer_fmt_v(...., va_list)`? If so, you should consider reaching upstream and file a bug.

Comment: Maybe this is just a symptom of my expectations I have from python

Comment: It would be also more easier, if instead of asking XY question, you would specify what exact function and library you are working and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have added some code, so I hope it's more clear now what I want to do.

Comment: Look for a `va_list` version of `make_buffer_fmt` and use that. If there isn't one, ask for it. If you can't wait for someone to write it for you, write it yourself. If you can't change the code (it's in somebody else's library) you can use a variadic template function: `template<typename...Args> int log_info(const char*fmt, Args...args) { return write_fmt(LOG_FILENO, LOG_INFO, fmt, args...); }`

Comment: I assume you are doing this as an educational exercise and not for any practical reason, otherwise I would point out that libfmt already exists as does std::format and std::print, which are far more sick. What you are doing with variadic functions is very much a C thing. In C++ you would prefer to use template variadics

Comment: You've told us about 3 wrapper functions, but you haven't told us whether the solution can change their type, or if that's carved in stone. None of the existing ones even have a parameter pack, because that's a template thing. Is it ok to change your variadic functions into variadic function templates?

Comment: nitpick - but `va_end` isn't getting called if you have a `return` statement in front of `write_fmt` .  `

Comment: @Chris_F Ok, it looks like I'm trying the reinvent the wheel here, I'm going to close this

Comment: @Useless The functions should have the '...', which means it's a template right? I'm gonna use the libfmt library now, but thank you all for answering.

Comment: No. `printf` uses `...` and definitely isn't a template, because it's existed for longer than those have. I think we're perhaps at the "read a good book" stage if you don't quite understand the syntax you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do pass on the parameter pack from `log` to `make_buffer_fmt`?

To start with, you need to *have* a parameter pack.

This is a C++ variadic function template with a parameter pack:

```
template <typename... Args>
int log(const char *fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    return write_fmt(LOG_FILENO, LOG_INFO, fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

You don't use `va_list` at all, because that's for dealing with C-style variadic function parameters after you've lost all the type information. In C++, you don't need to discard that type information in the first place (or at least not until you call a C-style function like `vsnprintf`)

The only (potential) disadvantage is that all these functions must be defined inline in the header. Since they're not really doing anything that seems worth hiding, I don't think that's a problem here.

---

Note that in your original version, `int write_fmt(int fd, char foo, const char* fmt, ...)` isn't suitable for calling with a `va_list` parameter anyway. This isn't like the `*args` parameter sequence in Python, it can't be expanded back into a variable-length parameter list. It's just a single struct.

That's why the standard library has both [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) and [`vsnprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf):

```
int snprintf(char* buffer, std::size_t buf_size, const char* format, ...);
int vsnprintf(char* buffer, std::size_t buf_size, const char* format, std::va_list vlist);
```

Anyway, `write_fmt` should be a similar perfect-forwarding passthrough to the above, and then `make_buffer_fmt` will either call `snprintf` with its expanded parameter pack:

```
template <typename... Args>
int make_buffer_fmt(char *buffer, size_t bufsize, const char *fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    return snprintf(buffer, bufsize, fmt,  std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

or `vsnprintf` with an explicit `va_list` (although there's really no benefit to doing this)

```
int make_buffer_fmt(char *buffer, size_t bufsize, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    int rc = vsnprintf(buffer, bufsize, fmt, va);
    va_end(va);
    return rc;
}
```

or [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) if you're ready to embrace the 21st century, and don't mind changing the format string syntax (or the dynamic allocation).