Unable to propagate variable args from one variadic function to another
I have read the following about passing arguments to variadic functions,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3530807/22299201
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdarg.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

void foo(char*, ...);
void wrapper(char*, va_list);
void bar(char*, ...);

int main() {
    char *format = "Unit testing this function %s";
    
    foo(format, "args1");

    return 0;
}

void foo(char *format, ...) {
    // code to capture output
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    char *temp = va_arg(args, char*);
    printf("args foo %s\n", temp);
    wrapper(format, args);
    va_end(args);
    // code to capture output
}

void bar(char *format, ...) {
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    char *temp = va_arg(args, char*);
    printf("args bar %s\n", temp);
    vsprintf(buffer, format, args);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    va_end(args);
}

void wrapper(char* format, va_list args) {
    bar(format, args);
    char *temp = va_arg(args, char*);
    printf("args wrapper %s\n", temp);
}

Output:
args foo args1
args bar 
Unit testing this function 
args wrapper args1

Let me explain the scenario:-

I have to unit-test a production function with a similar signature and logic as bar.
I am using acutest framework to test my code, main here can resemble that test function.
I am using a helper function, foo that has some logic to capture output of bar.
Based on the above link shared, it is impossible to pass variable arguments from foo to bar, hence passing to another wrapper function.

Why are args not being propagated to bar?
What am I doing wrong?

You can't call bar the way wrapper is doing and have it do what you want.  Think about what your code is doing.  You want bar to be passed a char * second 'argument.  But that's not what wrapper is passing to it. wrapper is instead passing a va_list to it.  Do you see how that can't possibly work?  Your leaf-level function needs to take a va_list argument.

Use the analogy of fprintf() and vfprintf().  The first takes a , ...) variable argument list; the second takes a va_list.  You'll need to do the same.

"Why are args not being propagated to bar?" -- for exactly the same reason you quote in your last bullet point, which is described in the linked answers. As a side-note, using vsprintf followed by printf is weakening your code. There is no reason to do that, and you open yourself up to buffer overflow attacks by using an insecure function with a fixed-size buffer and no checks. Just use vprintf and then output a newline (e.g. with puts("");).

See Forward an invocation of a variadic function in C?

Ouch, careful with the duphammer ... The linked answer and the doc page it links to don't discuss usage of va_copy (which my "hammered" answer did).
